# Support of ATL WebBrowser controls in Windows mobile 7.0

Tags: windows-mobile, webbrowser-control, atlcom

Just being curious, we would like to know the support for ATL webbrowser control (IWebBrowser2) is available on next windows mobile 7.0 version.

Can anybody confirm the same.

Thanks, 
Ramanand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft hasn't said *anything* about what's in the next version of WinMo so there's absolutely no way for us to know what will or will not be supported.  We can only guess, and with all of the secrecy and rumor, any guess is as good as the next.

You might guess this way:  It would be pretty major if they broke backward compatibility for something this fundamental.  Microsoft has a long history of backward compatibility, so it's very, very likely that it will work.

Or you might guess this way: Microsoft is going to make absolutely fundamental changes to the way the platform works.  They will lock down the device like they do with Zune and give you only a certain sandbox to play in.  That sandbox is managed code and you'll have limited or no access to APIs, so you won't be able to use it.

Again, these are both guesses, and you could guess anywhere in between as well.